# REST API - cant retrieve translated option values

Tags: magento2, rest-api

The main goal for me is to retrieve an option with all its labels, or a call to update labels and leaving the rest of the labels as it was.

I cant find any, tried all the repo calls so far

Answer (score 0):

We should take a look: http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/ > *catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1*

As we can see, we should use: **/V1/products/attributes/{attributeCode}/options**

```
[
  {
    "label": "string",
    "value": "string",
    "sort_order": 0,
    "is_default": true,
    "store_labels": [
      {
        "store_id": 0,
        "label": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Read more: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3430